# MVC Pattern, How to send signal from View to Controller when user clicks button

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, signals

For full insight: https://github.com/Markewycz/todo-list

I am creating Todo App.

I got stuck on trying to receive the signal in ActionsView when the user clicks the button so it can be passed to ActionsController where the CreateProject method will be invoked.

I just can't wrap my head around how to properly and effectively listen for clicks on add-project-btn without multiplying event listener on this btn.

index.js

```
import "./styles/main.scss";
import App from "./app/model/todoModel";
import InitialPage from "./app/views/initialPage";
import ProjectRenderController from "./app/controller/projectRenderController";
import ProjectActionsController from "./app/controller/projectActionsController";

const myApp = new App();
const initPage = new InitialPage();
const renderController = new ProjectRenderController(myApp, initPage);
const actionsController = new ProjectActionsController(myApp, renderController);

function initializeApp() {
  renderController.initializePage();
  renderController.switchProject(myApp.getProjects());
}

initializeApp();
```

actionsController.js

```
import ProjectActionsView from "../views/projectActionsView";

class ProjectActionsController {
  constructor(myApp, renderController) {
    this.myApp = myApp;
    this.actionsView = new ProjectActionsView();
    this.renderController = renderController;
  }

  createNewProject() {
    this.myApp.createProject("Your Project");
    this.renderController.appendProjectList(this.myApp.getProjects());
  }
}

export default ProjectActionsController;
```

actionsView.js

```
class ProjectActionsView {
  constructor() {
    this.btn = document.querySelector(".add-project-btn");

    this.btn.addEventListener("click", () => {});
  }
}
export default ProjectActionsView;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add code as text, not images. We can't debug images, copy/paste them, search for them, etc.